# Is there anyway to sign up for firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-console

Hi i'm trying to signup for firebase but i can't figure it out.

You can only login with google, GitHub.

But I'm sure there is a way to sign up its just that i can't figure it out.

And when i try login in with the others it does not take me to the dashboard.

That is why i'm wondering if you can sign up for firebase?

I have already googled it i didin't find the older site i could you could sign up right when you get on there but on the new site you can't.

Comment: To sign up for using Firebase, go to https://firebase.google.com/ and click SIGN IN at the top right of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can login [here](https://www.firebase.com/login/) on the older site. However, it seems like firebase is making google accounts mandatory [for the foreseeable future](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=10748726).

Comment: Ok thanks for the help, but there is know way just to sign up with firebase?

Comment: No, even the "I don't have a Google Account" button redirects to "[https://accounts.google.com/SignUpWithoutGmail](https://accounts.google.com/SignUpWithoutGmail)" which is just a google sign up form to create a Google Account.

Comment: and once i login with google how do i get to the dashboard

Comment: If you are referring to the "Status Dashboard," you can find it [here](https://status.firebase.google.com/)